# Performance difference between different ways to draw rectangles from textures in xna?

Tags: c#, xna, texture2d, drawrectangle

I am trying to developing p a JRPG/dungeon crawler as a summer project and I am atm cleaning up in my code. In the combat it exists "healthbars" and one healthbar consists of 3 rectangles that need to be drawn for each character (2-8 characters in total depending on the context means up to 24 healbar rectangles at one time).

My old way to draw the healbar was based on 1 texture where i took a single pixel from
and draw over a rectangle shaped area. Basicly i used the "HealtBar" texture as a color palet... for example if the source rectangle was (0, 0, 1, 1) it represented to draw a black rectangle.

```
Texture2D mHealthBar;
mHealthBar = theContentManager.Load<Texture2D>("HealthBar");

public override void Draw(SpriteBatch theSpriteBatch)
        {
            //draw healtbar
            theSpriteBatch.Draw(mHealthBar, new Rectangle((int)Position.X+5,
            (int)(Position.Y - 20), (MaxHealth * 5)+7, 15),
            new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1), Color.Black);

            theSpriteBatch.Draw(mHealthBar, new Rectangle((int)(Position.X + 8),
            (int)(Position.Y - 17), ((MaxHealth * 5)), (mHealthBar.Height) - 2),
            new Rectangle(2, 2, 1, 1), Color.White);

            theSpriteBatch.Draw(mHealthBar, new Rectangle((int)(Position.X + 8),
            (int)(Position.Y - 17), ((Health * 5)), (mHealthBar.Height) - 2),
            new Rectangle(3, 2, 1, 1), Color.Red);
      }
```

this aint a good looking solution... so instead i tried to create an abstract class that would reduce the amount of code and increase the amount of clarity in the code.

```
abstract class Drawer
{
    static private Texture2D _empty_texture;

    static public void DrawRect(SpriteBatch batch, Color color, Rectangle rect)
    {
        _empty_texture = new Texture2D(batch.GraphicsDevice, 1, 1);
        _empty_texture.SetData(new[] { Color.White });

        batch.Draw(_empty_texture, rect, color);
    }
}
```

With the new Drawer class I could throw away the "mHealthBar" variable and draw the rectangles in a more nice looking code way. But when I started to use the new way to draw the game started to have frame Rate problems, the old way was smooth...what is the reason to the frame rate problems?

```
        Drawer.DrawRect(theSpriteBatch, Color.Black, new Rectangle((int)Position.X+5,
        (int)(Position.Y - 20), (MaxHealth * 5)+7, 15));

        Drawer.DrawRect(theSpriteBatch, Color.White, new Rectangle((int)(Position.X + 8),
        (int)(Position.Y - 17), (MaxHealth * 5), 9));

        Drawer.DrawRect(theSpriteBatch, Color.Red, new Rectangle((int)(Position.X + 8),
        (int)(Position.Y - 17), (Health * 5), 9));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're creating a new texture and setting the colour every time you want to draw.

What you should do is only create the texture once (when loading your other content).